# Compared elementes of hash (subtraction) RUBY

Tags: ruby, hash

I have this structure

```
x = [8349310431, 8349314513]
y = [667984788, 667987788]
z = [148507632380, 153294624079]

map = Hash[x.zip([y, z].transpose).sort]
#=> {
#     8349310431=>[667984788, 148507632380],
#     8349314533=>[667987788, 153294624079]
#   }
```

and I need to compare, the keys with the rest of the keys, but if the subtraction of the keys is less than 100, you have to compare the first elements to which the key points and if this subtraction of elements is less than 100 the procedure is repeated with the second element that the key points to

example

```
 key[0] - key[1] = 8349310431−8349314533 = 4102 (with value absolute)
```

so now we subtract the first elements that the key points to, because it is greater than 100 the subtraction

```
element1Key1 - element1Key2 = 667984788 - 667987788 = 3000 (with value absolute)
```

as the subtraction is greater than 100 we repeat this with the second elements

```
 element2Key1 - element2Key2 = 15329460 - 15329462 = 2 (with value absolute)
```

as it is less than 100 we stop here and keep this in a counter can be

if the subtraction is less than 100 since the operation with the keys, it can not be stopped there, it is necessary to do it until the second element to which the key points.

but how do I do it

Sorry for my English, but I don't speak it, I hope you understand, and thanks

Comment: This question would be a lot easier on the eyes if the numbers were changed to 1-2 digits.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I'm in college and the data they will give us is that long

Comment: You could edit it for us.

Comment: _"we stop here and keep this in a counter can be"_ – what does that mean? How does your expected result look like?

Comment: From where 8349314533 is coming? And 15329460 and 15329462?

Comment: So many questions: "I need to compare, the keys with the rest of the keys" How many keys? When do we stop do we try key[n] against all other keys first before progressing on to the fallback logic or is it just `key[n]` vs `key[n+1]` and then `value[n][i]` vs `value[n+1][i]`. I guess sorting the `Hash` could simplify this greatly. Also is this consecutive or can a key value pair be reused e.g. what is the expected result for say `{200 => [200, 200], 301 => [400,201], 315 => [400,0]}`.

Comment: Also what happens if 2 keys meet the original condition `{200 =>[1,1], 205 => [2,2], 106 => [3,3]}` in this case `key[1]` and `key[2]` are both within 100 of `key[0]` and within 100 of each other how should this be handled when each one has 2 possible matches that meet the criteria should this result in `[[5,94],[5,99],[94,99]]` where those numbers are the absolute distance between the keys in this order?

Comment: Sidenote: Why 2 accounts [Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10598651/alejandro-rodriguez) and why 2 [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292598/compare-keys-of-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense?

```
x = [8349310431, 8349314513]
y = [667984788, 667987788]
z = [15329460, 15329462]

[x, y, z].detect { |a, b| (a-b).abs < 100 } # => [15329460, 15329462]
```

Just in case, why build a hash?